# Razor Tags in Included Javascript (in Separate File)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm interested in using more fine-grained Javascript include files to enhance maintainability.  However, I'm missing something.  Can I still "overwrite" or include sections from my Razor view context?  Let's say my Javascript include is as follows:

```
function CategoriesViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.searchMode = ko.observable("SEARCH");   // Wire up with Knockout.js
}
```

But, if this script were inline as part of my .cshtml Razor view, I'd be able to do something like this:

```
function CategoriesViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.searchMode = ko.observable("SEARCH");   // Wire up with Knockout.js
    self.categories = @Html.JSONFor(Model.LookupForCategories.Select(c => c.Text ));
}
```

(Without the syntax highlighting, I'll point out that I've included a server tag that places some Javascript code/data straight from my server-side ASP.MVC ViewModel.)

If I pull Javascript into separate files and include them, I lose this ability.  Is there a feature or technique that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are going to have to pass any server data to the javascript by adding some paramters on the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no. This is a common problem when dealing with serverside frameworks and js. You are pretty much stuck with parameterizing, or declaring variables either as globals, or as properties on some shared object.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it yet myself but you may be interested in the RazorJs nuget package: http://nuget.org/packages/RazorJS

More on the subject from the author here:
http://djsolid.net/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files